Drawing a computation tableau: arrows and row labels outside table
I am attempting to replicate the following diagram of a computation tableau in Sipser's Introduction to the Theory of Computation:

Here's what I have so far:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable, graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \(\#\) & \(q_{0}\) & \(z_0\) & \(z_{1}\)                    & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\dots} & \(z_n\) & \(\sqcup\) & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\dots} & \(\sqcup\) & \(\#\)
        \tabularnewline
        \hline
        \(\#\) &           &         & \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{\dots} & \(\#\)\tabularnewline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:comptableau}
\end{center}
\end{document}

I am at a loss on how to complete this table, particularly the labels and arrows.
Any help would be appreciated.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Does How to add arrow in equations and matrix? help?
